# Sorting strings, in a function, is my logic faulty or?

Tags: php, string

i need to sort some strings and match them with links, this is what i do:

```
$name_link = $dom->find('div[class=link] strong');
```

Returns array [0]-[5] containing strings such as NowDownload.eu

```
$code_link = $dom->find('div[class=link] code');
```

Returns links that match the names from 0-5, as in link [0] belongs to name [0]

I do not know the order in which they are returned, NowDownload.Eu, could be $code_link[4] or $code_link [3], but the name array will match it in order.

Now, i need $code_link[4] // lets say its NowDownload.Eu to become $link1 every time

so i do this

```
$i = 0;

while (!empty($code_link[$i]))

   SortLinks($name_link, $code_link, $i);  // pass all links and names to function, and counter
   $i++;
}

function SortLinks($name_link, $code_link, &$i) { // counter is passed by reference since it has to increase after the function

   $string = $name_link[$i]->plaintext; // name_link is saved as string
   $string = serialize($string); // They are returned in a odd format, not searcheble unless i serialize

   if (strpos($string, 'NowDownload.eu')) { // if string contains NowDownload.eu

       $link1 = $code_link[$i]->plaintext; 
       $link1 = html_entity_decode($link1); 
       return $link1; // return link1
   }

   elseif (strpos($string, 'Fileswap')) {

       $link2 = $code_link[$i]->plaintext; 
       $link2 = html_entity_decode($link2);
       return $link2;
   }

   elseif (strpos($string, 'Mirrorcreator')) {

       $link3 = $code_link[$i]->plaintext;
       $link3 = html_entity_decode($link3);
       return $link3;
   }

   elseif (strpos($string, 'Uploaded')) {

       $link4 = $code_link[$i]->plaintext;
       $link4 = html_entity_decode($link4);
       return $link4;
   }

   elseif (strpos($string, 'Ziddu')) {

       $link5 = $code_link[$i]->plaintext;
       $link5 = html_entity_decode($link5);
       return $link5;
   }

   elseif (strpos($string, 'ZippyShare')) {

       $link6 = $code_link[$i]->plaintext;
       $link6 = html_entity_decode($link6);
       return $link6;
   }
}


echo $link1 . '<br>';
echo $link2 . '<br>';
echo $link3 . '<br>';
echo $link4 . '<br>';
echo $link5 . '<br>';
echo $link6 . '<br>';
die();
```

I know they it finds the link, i have tested it before, but i wanted to make it a function, and it messed up, is my logic faulty or is there an issue with the way i pass the  variables/ararys ?

Comment: I'm still not clear on the problem.  Could you show us the data you have in a typical array, and how you would like that data sorted?

Comment: $name_link[0] could contain 'NowDownload.eu'

$code_link[0] would contain the link that belongs to 'Nowdownload.eu'

But, it is not certin that NowDownload.eu is inside $name_link[0] it could be in $name_link[4], but $code_link[4] would still be the link that belongs to $name_link[4]

And the $code_link with the string NowDownload.eu has to become $link1

Comment: Does that make any sense ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you pass `$i` as reference since you use it just for reading it. You could return an array contaning the named links and using it like so :

```
$all_links = SortLinks($name_link,$code_link);
echo $all_links['link1'].'<br/>';
echo $all_links['link2'].'<br/>';
```

You will have to put your loop inside the function, not outside.